# VUE Web component inside legacy app results in error "_Ctor, object is not extensible"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, web-component, vue-cli

I'm having trouble importing my custom component in my legacy app.
I pre-compiled my SFC as a webcomponent with vue-cli builder, and I import inside my main.js file this way :

```
import * as HelloWorld from '../dist/hello-world.js'
Vue.component('hello-world',HelloWorld); //if I add my component globally (same _Ctor error)
```

Then I load my app on a container div :

```
var app = new Vue({
    el:"#container",
  data: {
    test: 'Vue is init !' //just a test to validate init
  },
  components:{
        HelloWorld //my web component locally (same _Ctor error)
    }
});
```

When my app load, I get this JS error...
[image: JS error log when initializing app]

I noticed that when the page is loaded without the following component tag :

```
<hello-world></hello-world>
```

no error is thrown and if I add the component tag through JS after the page is loaded, component is properly working.
If I add this component outside of my Vue.el (#container) scope, it's working too.
However, I would like to add this component to #container.

I import Vue 2 through CDN.
Seems like a loading or building error but I can't get it.

Thanks for your help.

---

hello-world.js is a precompiled .VUE file with vue-cli, just a test file catching some events :

```
<template>
  <h1 v-on:click="clickon"
      v-on:mouseenter="addone"
  >{{msg}}</h1>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      msg: 'Hello world!'
    }
  },
  methods : {
    clickon: function () {
      // `this` inside methods points to the Vue instance
      alert('Clicked')
    },
    addone: function(){
      this.msg = 'Mouse entered'
    },

  }
}
</script>

<style>
h1{
  color:red;
}
</style>
```

Precompiled with :

```
vue build --target wc HelloWorld.vue
```

Comment: The problem is specific to hello-world.js. You didn't show it

Comment: I edited my post, hello-world.js is a precompiled .VUE file, content of this .VUE in the original post. Thank you.

Comment: It's default export, so it should be default import, not `*`. It's likely the problem here.

Comment: I tried : import HelloWorld from '../dist/hello-world.js'.
Result in : The requested module '..' does not provide an export named 'default'

Comment: It's not just precompiled, it's compiled as web component. See https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#web-component . You don't need to import HelloWorld component at all. It's not a component. It's *web* component

Comment: Ok I was really focused on the fact that I wanted to "register" this web component to my Vue instance through this script... in order to share datas. 
Is there any ways to share datas between those 2 except html datas/props ? Investigate on vuex ?

Comment: I got it working by building it with --target lib. I edited the post, thank you for your help and bringing me a new way to think after days struggling with that.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working by building it with `--target` lib and importing my JS file with:

```
import '../dist/HelloWorld.umd.js';
```

Then it can be added to my Vue instance with:

```
components:{
    "hello-world":HelloWorld
}
```

Seems to be the right way to do it; web components can't be imported this way.